# Processing boolean logic, no error noticed, but won't run

Tags: boolean, mouseevent, processing

```
//I will make a program that generates a square in the center of
//the screen if my mouse is located on the top half of the display
//and an ellipse if my mouse is located on the bottom half of the
//screen

//Global variables


int mouseposy;
float rect;
float ellipse;

//Setup

void setup() {
    size(600,600);
    mouseposy = mouseY;
}

//Draw

void draw() {
    background(0);
}

if {

    (mouseposy > 300);
    fill(mouseX,0,mouseY);
    rect(300,300,50,50);

} else {

    (mouseposy < 300);
    fill(mouseX,0,mouseY);
    ellipse(300,300,50,50);

}
```

By all means this should work, correct? This should give me a rectangle in the center of the display when I'm above 300px in the display coordinates, and an ellipse when I'm below 300px. Am I writing the if statement in the wrong section or something? When I press the run button, it just highlights the if statement and nothing else. I get no error message, just the highlight. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

///EDITED CODE///

```
//Global variables


int mouseposy;
float rect;
float ellipse;

//Setup

void setup() {
    size(600,600);
    mouseposy = mouseY;
}

//Draw

void draw() {
    mouseposy = mouseY;
    background(0);


if (mouseposy >= 300){

    fill(mouseX,0,mouseY);
    rect(300,300,50,50);

} else if(mouseposy =< 300) {


    fill(mouseX,0,mouseY);
    ellipse(300,300,50,50);

    }
}
```

I'm guessing I still have butchered one or another element of the code, but if anyone can see what's still wrong with this code I would appreciate the help. Now it is giving me the 'unexpected token: 300' error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three problems, first of all the syntax of an if statement is

```
if (condition) statement
```

In you example you don't have any condition at all, you have `mouseposy > 300` which you probably intended as a condition but used as a statement, which is an expression which discards its own result. Probably you meant something like

```
if (mouseposy > 300) {
  fill(...);
}
```

The second issue is the fact that you are using the variable `mouseposy` but it is set just in the `setup()` method, which is invoked once when the sketch starts and it is never updated, you should directly use `mouseY` variable or update it in your `draw` method.

The third issue is that the if/else statement doesn't cover all the cases, since you have

```
if (foo < 300) { .. }
else if (foo > 300) { ..}
```

What happens when `foo == 300`? You should use an `>=` operator or turn the second `else if` into an `else`.

Comment: What are the benefits of choosing either approach? Also, I just have an else statement there on the bottom, do I not? Sorry for the derp, but still grasping at concepts here.

Comment: Also, I updated the mouseposY variable and changed the operator types on those if else statements. Somehow it doesn't want to recognize the number 300 now. I'll post and edit of the code above.

Comment: The operator is `<=` not `=<`. You don't need to have `<=` though since you already cover it in first if case. You just need <.

Comment: You are awesome, dude. The code works perfectly now.